# Dojo: loop with data binding

Tags: angularjs, dojo

I'm just starting with Dojo, and I'm really impressed with the amount and quality of all the modules. Coming from AngularJS however, I find the two-way data binding of [Dojo's MVC](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/data_modeling/) a bit lacking.

Is there really no way to subscribe to a Dojo Object Store, have a loop in a template to iterate over the items in the store and having the view update automagically when items are added/removed? The [example tutorial](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/data_modeling/) uses `dojo/store/Observable` to implement this cumbersome logic:

```
results.observe(function(item, removedIndex, insertedIndex){
    // this will be called any time a item is added, removed, and updated
    if(removedIndex > -1){
        removeRow(removedIndex);
    }
    if(insertedIndex > -1){
        insertRow(item, insertedIndex);
    }
}, true);
function insertRow(item, i){ ... }
function removeRow(i){ ... }
```

In AngularJS you would do something like this:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in results">
  <span>{{item.text}}</span>
</li>
```

So do I have to choose between Dojo's extensive widget and modules collection and AngularJS's straight-forward templating with two-way data binding?

Comment: What are you using Dojo for?  What sort of app?  I used Dojo in the past, then Dojo + Angular, then got rid of Dojo and was very happy :-).  Get rid of Dojo if you can.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**First of all, congrats on coming over to the Dojo side.** Yes AngularJS is extremely convenient for 2 way data bindings, but you'll soon find out that as an application grows more complex, you'll be needing the help of the powerful (and numerous) Dojo / Dijit / Dojox modules.

You are right dojo/Observable currently provides binding via store in Dojo. It can really achieve the same power as AngularJS. Checkout [dgrid examples](http://dojofoundation.org/packages/dgrid/js/dgrid/test/OnDemand.html) for a demo.

For convenience, a module has been made for binding in a format similar to Angular JS. Its called [dbind](https://github.com/kriszyp/dbind). It can be used independently currently and will soon be integrated into Dojo's core. You should also check [dojox/mvc/Bind](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/mvc/Bind.html)